# Hard attention derivations

Tags: probability, likelihood, gradient, attention

I am trying to completely understand the paper [Show, Attend and Tell: Neural Image Caption Generation with Visual Attention](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03044.pdf). I understand the paper conceptually. I am trying to understand the math involved. I am probably weak in Bayesian statistics.

I got stuck on the hard attention.

There are two formulas that I don't understand. First of all, I don't understand derivation of objective function $L_s$ - It is start of the derivation of variational
lower bound on the marginal log-likelihood of observing the sequence of words **y** given image features **a** and locations **s**
\begin{align}
&= \sum_{s} p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \log (\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a}) \\
&\leq \log \sum_{s} p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) p (\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})\\ &= p(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{a}) 
\end{align}

The second thing that is difficult is the derivations of a gradient in equation (6). I understand what the author of the paper is doing here and where parameter W is later used, but I don't understand the formula itself. Especially multiplications by $p(s |a)$ (which is for some reason missing in equation (7)) and $\log p(y| s,a)$.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L_s}{\partial W}
&= \sum_{s} p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \left[ \frac{\partial \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})}{\partial W} + \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a}) \frac{\partial \log p(s \mid \mathbf{a})}{\partial W}\right] \\
\end{align}
Could you nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Please explain your notation so that readers don't have to look up everything in your references just to know whether they might be able to answer the question.

Comment: Adding to this: there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: Thank you, for comments. I will edit answer accordingly, fill more details and rewrite equations to LaTex.  I never realized, what is the impact, but I will write everything in LaTex from now-on, where it is possible.

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can copy a lot of the LaTeX from my answer below to save some time+effort, if you’d like that as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you, again I copied a "little bit" :D. I hope that everything is cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Many thanks for your friendly responses and attention to improving your post! +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good news: You don't need to know Bayesian statistics for these derivations. Just a bit of probability and a bit of calculus.

---

Let's look at $L_s$ first.

Moving from the first line to the second is an application of **Jensen's inequality**, which rears its head often in ML. $L_s$ is a lower bound on the log-likelihood in this latent variable model. Moving from the second to the third is done by marginalizing out $S$, using the law of total probability.

It may be helpful to work in the opposite direction, from line 3 to 2 to 1, for a clearer story. We start at the log-likelihood of the model. Then we introduce a latent variable into the model. Then we lower-bound the new likelihood.

---

Now for its partial derivative with respect to the parameters $W$.

First, recall the **sum rule** for derivatives. This lets you push the derivative operator into the summation.

$$\frac{\partial L_s}{\partial W} = \sum_s \frac{\partial}{\partial W} p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})$$

Second, recall the **product rule**. It lets us turn each summand into this:

$$p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \frac{\partial \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})}{\partial W} + \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a}) \frac{\partial p(s \mid \mathbf{a})}{\partial W}$$

This is close to what the paper presents, but not quite there. The last step we need is the **log-derivative trick**, which comes in on the last line below—after the factoring.

\begin{align}
\text{summand} &= p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \frac{\partial \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})}{\partial W} + \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a}) \frac{\partial p(s \mid \mathbf{a})}{\partial W} \\
&= p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \frac{\partial \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})}{\partial W} + \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a}) \frac{p(s \mid \mathbf{a})}{p(s \mid \mathbf{a})} \frac{\partial p(s \mid \mathbf{a})}{\partial W} \\
&= p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \left[ \frac{\partial \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})}{\partial W} + \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a}) \frac{1}{p(s \mid \mathbf{a})} \frac{\partial p(s \mid \mathbf{a})}{\partial W}\right] \\
&= p(s \mid \mathbf{a}) \left[ \frac{\partial \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a})}{\partial W} + \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid s, \mathbf{a}) \frac{\partial \log p(s \mid \mathbf{a})}{\partial W}\right] \\
\end{align}

And with that, we've recreated the formula from the paper.

---

P.S. The $p(y| s,a)$ is intentionally missing from equation (7), instead replaced by the $\frac{1}{N}$. It's a Monte Carlo estimate of the gradient, so we replace the true probability distribution with the empirical distribution.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, I was looking for some complexity and forgot about basic math. You are a life saver!